# Show 1200px wide div on mobile without mobile media queries applying

Tags: html, css, responsive

I want to make a div displayed on a desktop (say 1200px wide) appear on a mobile device (say 400px wide) and will scale the div 33% ratio so the 1200px appears within the 400px.

This is all fine, but the media queries are still applying it as if it were 400px because that is the mobile screen width. Is it possible to prevent media queries applying to this div - it should be treated exactly the same as the desktop styling.

As an example, imaging a vuetify or bootstrap grid system. I have 3 columns on the desktop, and when I scale that on the mobile I still want 3 columns on the mobile view. Currently, it is still 1200px wide but shown in one column. I'd the ability to toggle this behavior and show either the original desktop layout, or have the responsive view.

Comment: Does this `<div>` have content like text, images, etc. ? If so, there a ton of other factors to consider than just a `<div>`'s dimensions. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: It could have anything. However it renders on the desktop, id want the identical on the mobile (just smaller, scaled to match the new width) I'll work on a reproduction

Comment: To make sure I fully understand - Is it just the one element (which may itself have children which are affected by media queries which you want to be ignored)that you want to show this way, while there are other sibling elements which must remain affected by media width?

Comment: I can only think of putting it in an iframe (suitably encoded and with enough of the relevant CSS). Showing a minimal but representative amount of code would help us greatly here.

Comment: Do you set the width in px? Then that is the issue, because if element has a fixed size in pixels then it will be the same on all other devices, no matter the screen size. If you want to make the width responsive, try making the width in %, width: 100% and in addition you can add max-width: 1200px, so the element doesn't get wider than 1200px. And to make the height in ratio, add aspect-ratio: 1 / 3 to the element